# Magento 2 emails not being sent on VPS

Tags: magento2, nginx

I install Magento 2 on my server VPS: ubuntu 16.04, Nginx 1.10, MySQL 5.7, PHP 7. Site works, but can not sign on subscribe "Something went wrong with your subscription.". Transfer emails not works too. What have I done wrong? Maybe I need something to install on a server More?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Postfix is installed and configured as a NULL Client.

Install postfix by `apt-get install postfix` and configure in accordance with this [official postfix guide](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client)