# order confirmation email not send in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, email, smtp, send-mail

I Installed magento 2 on my vps server 
and  configured store email like [this](http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-email-configuration/)

but order confitmation email will not send to the customers 
what should I do , should I setup cron as some link recomended to do this 
or should I configure my server like [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146596/magento-2-emails-not-being-sent-on-vps)
what is the problem?

Comment: Try with configured cron.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I am also facing the same issue. I have tried all the above soln but not worked for me. Please help me with this.

Comment: Yes it was a cron issue

Answer (score 17):

If you have properly configured Magento 2 mailing systems, you may need to check below point:

1. Got to **`Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System`**

Under **Mail Sending Settings** make sure `Disable Email Communications` is set to `No`. Also verify your `Host` and `Port` fields if you are using any external mailing server.

2. Got to **`Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails`**

Under **General Settings** tab, choose `Asynchronous sending` to `Disable`

Under `Order` tab `Enabled` to `Yes`

Now clear/refresh your cache.

Hope this helps you. This solution is tested with Magento 2.1.0

Comment: There is no "Asynchronous sending"

Comment: What is the magento version you are using?

Comment: It's Magento/2.2 (Community)

Comment: I have an issue in Magento 2.2.7

Comment: not working with 2.2.7

Comment: Please permit me to love you *muahhhhhhhhhhh* Gosh for months! You are Americas next president. I believe in you

Comment: Does still not send any mail

Answer (score 4):

This will work.

> The transportbuilderbystore class has already been deprecated in 2.3
> and soon will be in 2.2.
>
> Fixed in Magento 2.2.7.

Fix:
vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/SenderBuilder.php

replace

```
    $this->transportBuilderByStore->setFromByStore(
        $this->identityContainer->getEmailIdentity(),
        $this->identityContainer->getStore()->getId()
    );
```

with

```
    $this->transportBuilder->setFrom(
        $this->identityContainer->getEmailIdentity(), 
        $this->identityContainer->getStore()->getId()
    );
```

vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php

replace

```
/**
 * Set mail from address
 *
 * @param string|array $from
 * @return $this
 */
public function setFrom($from)
{
    $result = $this->_senderResolver->resolve($from);
    $this->message->setFrom($result['email'], $result['name']);
    return $this;
}
```

with

```
/**
 * Set mail from address
 *
 * @param string|array $from
 * @return $this
 */
public function setFrom($from, $store = null)
{
    $result = $this->_senderResolver->resolve($from, $store);
    $this->message->setFrom($result['email'], $result['name']);
    return $this;
}
```

and just like that we do not need the TransportBuilderByStore anymore and it works as expected.

Comment: not working , if i used this solution email sending stop

Comment: Check this.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16355

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that the actual issue was caused because of "from" header. It was being set twice by some reason. Please update below file to get resolve this issue:

vendor\magento\framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilderByStore

```
public function setFromByStore($from, $store)
{
    $result = $this->senderResolver->resolve($from, $store);
    $this->message->setFrom($result['email'], $result['name']);

    return $this;
}
```

To

```
public function setFromByStore($from, $store)
{
    $result = $this->senderResolver->resolve($from, $store);

    if ($this->message->getFrom()) {
        $this->message->clearFrom();
    }

    $this->message->setFrom($result['email'], $result['name']);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: not working this solution for me 2.2.7

Comment: @NavinBhudiya Have you resolved this issue? I am also facing the same issue. I have tried all above soln but not worked for me. Please help me on this.