# Magento 2 not sending emails

Tags: magento2, email, order-email, order-confirmation

My Magento 2 webshop don't send any email. My cronjob is running and 
The settings are the same as in this ticket: [order confirmation email not send in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152799/order-confirmation-email-not-send-in-magento-2)

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

I'm using Magento 2.1.5

Answer (score -2):

Create simple php script on root of magento and check if its working or not. Change `$to` and `$from` email address.

```
<?php
$to = "your email address";
$subject = "PHP Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "random email address";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: I have received the email

Comment: then php mail is working fine.

Comment: Yes, I know. So the problem is in my Magento webshop? Do you have another idea?