# Email not sent on order conformation in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, order-email

I have created a custom module to send the email to the admin programatically on order place. But it does not send the email.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

> Vendor/Neworder/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="new_order_notification" instance="Vendor\Neworder\Observer\NewOrder" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Neworder/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Neworder\Helper;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\View as CustomerViewHelper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {

    /**
     * Neworder form data
     */
    protected $_data;

    /**
     * Initialize
     *
     * @param Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Fetch System Config Value
     */
    public function getConfigVal($str = '') {
        return $this->scopeConfig
                        ->getValue($str, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }

}
```

> Vendor/Neworder/Observer/NewOrder.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Neworder\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class NewOrder implements ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * Get extension configuration helper
     * @var \Hiddentechies\Testimonials\Helper\Config
     */
    public $dataHelper;

    /**
     * Pricing Helper
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data
     */
    public $curHelper;

    /**
     * Sales order Model
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    protected $order;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Hiddentechies\Neworder\Helper\Config $dataHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        \Hiddentechies\Neworder\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $curHelper
    ) {
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        $this->curHelper = $curHelper;
    }

    protected function _sendEmail($from, $to, $templateId, $vars, $store, $area = \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND) {
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
                ->setTemplateOptions([
                    'area' => $area,
                    'store' => $store->getId()
                ])
                ->setTemplateVars($vars)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($to['email'], $to['name']);
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();

        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

        return true;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $isNewOrderEnable = $this->dataHelper->getConfigVal('newordersection/generalgroup/enabled');
        // Check if new order email notification enabled
        if($isNewOrderEnable){

            // Set current order details
            $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
            $order = $this->order->load($orderIds);
            $orderIncId = $order->getIncrementId();

            // Set email config options
            $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
            $from = $this->dataHelper->getConfigVal('newordersection/generalgroup/send_from');
            $to = [
                'email' => $this->dataHelper->getConfigVal('newordersection/generalgroup/email'),
                'name' => 'Administrator'
            ];
            $templateId = $this->dataHelper->getConfigVal('newordersection/generalgroup/template');
            $subject = $this->dataHelper->getConfigVal('newordersection/generalgroup/subject');

            // Set email template variables
            $vars = [
                'admin_subject' => $subject,
                'cur_order_id' => "#".$orderIncId,
            ];

            // Call send email function with the necessary parameters
            $this->_sendEmail($from, $to, $templateId, $vars, $store);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152799/order-confirmation-email-not-send-in-magento-2

Comment: Are you able to place an order?

Comment: ARUNPRABAKARAN, not till now. Please help.

Comment: what is your exact error? not able to order or mail not send?

Comment: The Mail not send.

Comment: Did you try in local or dev instance?