# order confirm dont send any email Magento2

Tags: magento2.3, email, order-email, server-setup

I am using magento 2.3
When I try placeorder. It doesn't have any mail.
I use mail server. 
My mail sender: name@myserver.com

If I use SMPT module and change sender email to gmail then it works.
So, I think it relate to some setting for mail server or I am missing some step.
Anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you have properly configured Magento 2 mailing systems, you may need to check below point:

**Got to Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System**
Under Mail Sending Settings to make sure Disable Email Communications is set to No. Also, verify your Host and Port fields if you are using any external mailing server.

**Got to Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails
Under the General Settings tab, choose Asynchronous sending to Disable**

Under Order tab Enabled to Yes

Now clear/refresh your cache also **check-in log** file. Another way setup cron or not check below command

**//cron setup**

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento cron:install
```

**//cron run manually**

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento cron:run
```

**//cron list**

```
crontab -l
```

please more refer to this hope working [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152799/order-confirmation-email-not-send-in-magento-2) also [useful](https://magecomp.com/blog/fix-wrong-sales-order-email-sender-issue-in-magento-2/).

Comment: Vishal, I have same your setting. However, it effect with mail server like my email sender: name@myserver.com.    If I use gmail then it sends mail normally

Comment: Gmail is working because have already account exists but name@myserver.com email already create on the server ?

Comment: I have to fetch same issue like Gmail work but another ID not working so you need to check ID in particular server exits or not.

Comment: Yes, I have created account email on server. My account exist. So I dont sure about what the issues in here

Comment: are you check this link https://magecomp.com/blog/fix-wrong-sales-order-email-sender-issue-in-magento-2/