# Magento 2.3.3 - Sales email not set

Tags: email-templates, sales, magento2.3.3

After upgrade Magento 2.3.3, sales emails are not receiving. Please refer attached file.

[image]

Comment: Have you configured email?

Comment: @Priya, Have you checked the error log file?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152799/order-confirmation-email-not-send-in-magento-2   i think is similar to your thread

Comment: @Dhaduk Mitesh, I had checked it is correct.

Comment: @sanjay, I checked log file too, can't find the email error.

Comment: @Priya - You do know that the email class was completely changed in 2.3.3, so old email sending systems stopped working.  Have you updated you email sending code?

Comment: @Anthony - Hi, i did not change email sending code. Please let me know in which file nee to change?

Comment: @Priya Sorry i don't know.  I have not upgraded due to the change in the email classes.  I don't have time to fix or update all of the modules at the moment.  You could start here https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Backward-incompatible-Changes-in-the-Mail-Library-for-Magento-2/ba-p/144787

Comment: @Anthony - Okay thank you, i will check it

Comment: @Priya No worries.  There is a link on that page to a backward compatibility patch i believe which you could try applying