# Magento 2 - Sender Name doesn't appear in web-mail

Tags: magento2, email, order-email

In Magento 2, I defined sender names and emails in `Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Store Email Addresses`.

In `Sales > Emails` I set the new order confirmation email sender.

But when I go to my Webmail (Gmail but same for others webmails) there is no sender name there is only an email address.

Do you know why and how to make a sender name appear in webmail?

**EDIT**

In admin I set :

Sender Name: Test

Sender Email: "contact@test.com"

[image]

Why in Gmail Sender Name is "contact" and not "Test" ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: can you share screenshot.you what want to ???

Comment: @MohitPatel I add screenshot, see my Edit

Comment: try this :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152799/order-confirmation-email-not-send-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

I always face the same issue on Magento.

The solution I have used is editing the order_new.html email on cPanel.

You may also check if you have properly configurated on stores > settings > sales > sales emails.

Good luck